# Android Room, adding library data classes to database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

There is a shared library that is used by a desktop application as well as an android application.  The shared library contains no android libraries.  The shared library contains a set of data classes.  I would like to annotate these data classes as Room @Entity and add them to a database on the android client.  The desktop application has no need of a database.  Is there an easy way to do this?  The only option I can think of so far is to: change the classes from data classes (since data classes cannot be extended).  then extend these classes only in the android application and add the annotations.

Edit: Another way to ask this is, what can be done if there is a (possibly non-open) POJO in another library that wants to be added in Room?